# Working out 2 dates

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is, twice a day a script will run via cron, it checks the date a user purchased a service (`purchased_added` is the column). I want to check which purchase dates are 27 days before today's date e.g.

Service purchased on: **2017-02-09 02:01:35** 27 days from them would be: **2017-03-08 02:01:35** once the script finds targets it would send off an email.

So far I have:

```
if (isset($_GET['notify'])) {
        include('includes/db_connection.php');
        include('includes/functions.php');
        // first get all the purchased dates out...
        $dates = DB::getInstance()->select('SELECT * FROM `purchased` ORDER BY `purchased_added` ASC'); 
        foreach ($dates as $r) { 
          echo $r['purchased_added'] . "<br />";
          // dates - purchased & now
          //$datePur = date('m.d.y', strtotime($row['purchased_added'])
          //$dateNow = date('m.d.y');
          // any links due for payment?
          if (date('m.d.y', strtotime($r['purchased_added']. ' + 27 days')) < date('m.d.y')) {
            // email these users
          }
        }
}
```

My if statement looks wrong to me, is there an easier way to accomplish this? I feel I'm over complicating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could either compare directly timestamps:

```
if(strtotime($r['purchased_added']. ' + 27 days') < time())
```

or use a date format which is compatible with the desired sorting ('17.02.09' < '17.03.08' but this will be in general violated should the day/year be flipped):

```
if(date('y.m.d', strtotime($r['purchased_added']. ' + 27 days')) < date('y.m.d'))
```

or it would be perhaps best to use `DateTime`:

```
$current_dt = new DateTime("now");
$dt = new DateTime($r['purchased_added']. ' + 27 days');
if($dt < $current_dt)
    ....
```

or even

```
$current_dt = date_create("now");
if(date_create($r['purchased_added']. ' + 27 days') < $current_dt)
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) i will test all your suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you implement this logic in SQL query itself. You may also add an index to purchased_added if your table has many rows. And you can also add a column to flag once the email is sent (or how many emails sent).

```
SELECT * FROM `purchased` WHERE `purchased_added` < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -27 DAY)
```

This will only return rows where purchased_added is older than 27 days ago.

This way you are not reading all records from the table, and later can simply add an index if table grows big.

Comment: If you do not flag the records where emails are sent, you will be sending emails every time the cron runs.